# Spring Reactive Oauth 2.0 client grant type refresh token

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, token, refresh

Spring boot 3.1.4, Spring boot starter reactive oauth client libray.
I want to generate oauth 2.0 token for grant type refresh_token .
My requirement is to also pass refresh_token while generating the access token. I am setting Web Client exchange function for this. Please advise for the correct configuration. also advise how to pass refresh token while generating the access token. Refresh token has long life.

```
// client registration
 ` @Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("registration-id")
                .clientId("cliend_id")
                .clientSecret("client_secret")
                .tokenUri("token_uri")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .build();
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }
    // web client exchange server function
    private ExchangeFilterFunction getOAuth2FilterFunction(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository
                                                                   clientRegistrationRepository){

        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService =
                new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new

        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
        (clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .refreshToken()
                        .build();
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2FilterFunction =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth2FilterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("registration-id");
        return oauth2FilterFunction;
    }
      // web client configure with exchange filter
    @Bean
    public WebClient soapWebClient(final WebClient.Builder builder, 
                      final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        WebClient webClient = builder
                .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
                       
        exchangeFilterFunctions.add(getOAuth2FilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository));

                })
                .build();

        return webClient;
    }`
```

It is not working for me. During web service call, Oauth token not passed.`